# Adding to lists and loops

Tags: c#, list, loops

I've developed a new found interest in programming however I have had some problems. I have tried to make a simple program in which a user enters 10 numbers, if the number is 0 it will stop, then adds those numbers to a list then prints the list at the end. However, my program only asks for 4 numbers before stopping, it doesn't stop when 0 is entered and the "Enter a number message" at the start prints 3 times each time it goes round the loop.

Any help would be appreciated

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // I want to make a list
            // keep asking the user for values
            // which will then add those values onto the list
            // then print the list
            // create a list
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            int count = 0;

            while (count < 10) {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to add to the list");
                int number = Console.Read();
                list.Add(number);

                if (number == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                count++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The final list looks like this");

            foreach (int number in list) {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just edited your code to match indents and brackets. I suggest you make this a rule of thumb as this will often make it easier for you to find the problem.

Comment: Advice: rather than doing a `while` and handling the `count` yourself, here, you could simplify your life using `for(int count=0 ; count < 10 ; count++)`

Comment: Make yourself familiar with the debugger. Debugging is by far easier than staring at the code and reasoning about it.

Comment: Thank you both very much, massive help I am grateful!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with **Console.Read()** - It reads a **byte** rather than a string that should be converted into int in your case.

What you're looking for is Console.ReadLine(), surrounded with int.Parse(). Something like this:

```
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Although this may result in an exception if the user didn't input a valid number. You should always make sure that it's a number by `int.TryParse()` first.